# Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array, How to declare an Array in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongo schema, I'm trying to update yes/no/usersId with multiple value

```
var answersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
questionId: String,
usersId: Array,
yes: Array,
no: Array,
white: Array,
created : { type: Number, default: (new Date()).getTime() },
});
```

and this is my operation

```
answer.update({
                         $addToSet: { 
                            uersId: data.userId,
                            yes: data.userId
                        } 
                    }, function(updateResponse){
                        console.log('---------------------------------------> cb yes update',updateResponse)
                        result.answer = answer;
                        if (cb !== undefined && cb !== null) {
                            cb(result);
                        }
                    })
```

and this is my error

```
Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array
```

I know it's something stupid maybe I'm tired maybe someone know the problem.

Comment: What that error message is telling you is that the document you're updating has an existing field that's the target of `$addToSet` that isn't an array.  Is `uersId` in your `$addToSet` object just a typo in the question or is that in your code as well?  I'm assuming that should be `usersId`.

Comment: thx for answer, userId is in my code, i'm trying to keep out userId to prevent this, and now i'm testing with $push/$pushAll but it's the same error. I'm think it's my declaration of my schema but i'm not sure, and i don't find it in the net

Comment: I don't think this error could be caused by schema problems, but you should still define the array fields in your schema with actual types (e.g. `{type: [Number]}`).  If you're still getting that error with just `userId`, then that field isn't an array in the document you're updating.

Comment: Ok, i think i know where is the problem thank to you, i'm going to test and i come back post the result

Comment: The problem is i haven't define the array fields, thanks you very much johnyHK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my new mongo answer schema

```
var answersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
questionId: String,
usersId: [{ type: String, ref: 'Users' }],
yes: [{ type: String, ref: 'Users' }],
no: [{ type: String, ref: 'Users' }],
white: [{ type: String, ref: 'Users' }],
created : { type: String, default: (new Date()).getTime() },
});
```

i define the field  into the array, so it's work fine